# Find oldest but active following action

Tags: sql, postgresql

My table looks like this:

```
+----+-----------+--------+------------------------+
| ID |   type    | userID |          time          |
+----+-----------+--------+------------------------+
|  1 | FOLLOW    |      1 | 2017-09-22 13:47:00+00 |
|  2 | FOLLOW    |      2 | 2017-09-22 13:48:00+00 |
|  3 | FOLLOW    |      3 | 2017-09-22 13:49:00+00 |
|  4 | UNFOLLOW  |      1 | 2017-09-22 13:50:00+00 |
|  5 | UNFOLLOW  |      3 | 2017-09-22 13:51:00+00 |
|  6 | FOLLOW    |      3 | 2017-09-22 13:52:00+00 |
|  7 | FOLLOW    |      4 | 2017-09-22 13:53:00+00 |
|  8 | FOLLOW    |      1 | 2017-09-22 13:54:00+00 |
|  9 | UNFOLLOW  |      2 | 2017-09-22 13:55:00+00 |
+----+-----------+--------+------------------------+
```

It describes all follow actions a user has taken. I'm trying to write a query, which finds the oldest but still active `FOLLOW` action. Active means, that there is no `UNFOLLOW` action after that. I wasn't able to find a solution which works with a single Query.

In this example the result should be row #6.

[Fiddle with example data](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/a5c61/4)

Comment: Do you want this per user id?  Or overall?

Comment: @GordonLinoff Overall. In the real-world there will be another column which defines which user took this action. This is just a simplified version for StackOverflow.

Comment: . . It just seems strange to me, because the "unfollow" is per user, but the result is over all users.

Comment: @GordonLinoff The userID stands for which user is being followed/unfollowed. This table contains only the data for one user's actions. I hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hmmm.  Here is one method using `not exists`:

```
select distinct on (userId) t.*
from t
where not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.userId = t.userId and t2.type = 'UNFOLLOW' and
                        t2.time > t.time
                 )  and
      t.type = 'FOLLOW'
order by t.userId, t.time asc;
```

This returns the old active follow *per user id*.

EDIT:

The above assumes that you want the information for each user -- that makes sense to me.  But if you want the one oldest, then:

```
select t.*
from actions t
where not exists (select 1
                  from actions t2
                  where t2.userId = t.userId and t2.type = 'UNFOLLOW' and t2.time > t.time
                 )  and
      t.type = 'FOLLOW'
order by t.time asc
fetch first 1 row only;
```

[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/8aed4/4) is the SQL Fiddle for this version.

Answer (score 0):

This query will retrieve the the latest record for each user only if it is a FOLLOW;

```
select * from actions where id in (
  select a.id from actions as a where
  a.time = (select max(time) from actions where userid = a.userid)
  and a.type = 'FOLLOW');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
    (SELECT ID, Type, userID, rank() OVER(PARTITION BY userID ORDER BY fDate DESC) AS seqnum
    FROM flw 

    ) T 
    WHERE seqnum = 1 AND 
    T.type <> 'UNFOLLOW'
```